# Java, how to use compareTo to sort an Arraylist

Tags: java, comparable, compareto

Im trying to figure out how to sort an ArrayList using comparable, my code looks like this:

```
 public class playerComparsion{

        public static void main(String[] args){ 


    ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();      

        Player p1 = new Players(1,92,Zlatan);
    Player p2 = new Players(2,92,Hazard);
    Player p3 = new Players(1,82,Klose);

    list.add(p1);
    list.add(p2);
    list.add(p3);
        }
    } 
        class Players implements Comparable{

        int position;
             String name;
            int rating;

            public Players(int i, int j, String string)  {

                this.position=i;
                this.rating=j;
                this.name=string;
            }

             public void getRating() {
                    System.out.println(this.rating);
                    }
             public void getPos() {
                    System.out.println(this.position);
                    }
             public void getName() {
                    System.out.println(this.name);
                    }

            @Override
            public int compareTo(Object o) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return 0;
            }

        }
```

I want to sort the Arraylist based on the attribute rating. I suppose I should use the compareTo function but I have no idea how, can someone help me?

Comment: compareTo compares two Players and it is supposed to return a negative, positive or zero number depending if it sorts before, after or at the same position.

Answer (score 12):

Instead of making `Player` implement `Comparable`, you get more flexibility by implementing `Comparator<Player>` classes. For example:

```
class PlayerComparatorByRating implements Comparator<Player> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Player o1, Player o2) {
        return o1.getRating() - o2.getRating();
    }
}

class PlayerComparatorByName implements Comparator<Player> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Player o1, Player o2) {
        return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
    }
}
```

After all, `Player` has multiple fields, it's easy to imagine that sometimes you might want to order players differently. A great advantage of this approach is the *single responsibility principle*: a `Player` class does only one thing, encapsulates player data. Instead of adding one more responsibility (sorting), it's better to move that logic in another class.

You could use these comparators with `Collections.sort`, for example:

```
Collections.sort(list, new PlayerComparatorByRating());
System.out.println(list);
Collections.sort(list, new PlayerComparatorByName());
System.out.println(list);
```

#### Extra tips

Your class seems to be named `Players`. It's better to rename to `Player`.

The `getName`, `getRating`, `getPos` methods should not return `void` and print the result, but return the field values instead.

Use better names for the constructor arguments, for example:

```
Player(int position, int rating, String name) {
    this.position = position;
    this.rating = rating;
    this.name = name;
}
```

Use the right type of list to store players:

```
List<Player> list = new ArrayList<Player>();
```

Please format your code properly. Any IDE can do that.

#### Suggested implementation

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

class Player {
    private int position;
    private int rating;
    private final String name;

    Player(int position, int rating, String name) {
        this.position = position;
        this.rating = rating;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    public int getPos() {
        return position;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s:%d:%d", name, position, rating);
    }
}

class PlayerComparatorByRating implements Comparator<Player> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Player o1, Player o2) {
        return o1.getRating() - o2.getRating();
    }
}

class PlayerComparatorByName implements Comparator<Player> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Player o1, Player o2) {
        return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
    }
}

public class PlayerComparatorDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        List<Player> list = new ArrayList<Player>();

        Player p1 = new Player(1, 92, "Zlatan");
        Player p2 = new Player(2, 92, "Hazard");
        Player p3 = new Player(1, 82, "Klose");

        list.add(p1);
        list.add(p2);
        list.add(p3);

        Collections.sort(list, new PlayerComparatorByRating());
        System.out.println(list);
        Collections.sort(list, new PlayerComparatorByName());
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just browsing arround; should you do a null check in your compare methods??

Comment: Good question. If you allow null values in your collections, then yes, you must add null checks.

Comment: Nice, I liked what you did here very infomative

Answer (score 5):

Don't use a raw type with `Comparable`.  Instead, use `Comparable<Players>`.  This way, you have direct access to the object you care about without having to cast from `Object`.

The sample `compareTo` would be this:

```
public int compareTo(Player other) {
    return rating - other.getRating();
}
```

Then, you would actually have to...sort it, using `Collections.sort()`.

```
Collections.sort(list);
```

The reason for `Comparable<Players>` is that `Comparable` itself [is defined as taking a generic type `T`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).

Comment: You can access rating directly, if you do it from any method in `Player`, even for another instance, i.e. `other.rating` can be used instead of `other.getRating()`. Also it should be mentioned that the substraction may overflow and produce a illegal value if  negative ratings are allowed.

Comment: I dont understand how to USE the compareTo function. I want to sort the Arraylist "list".

Comment: The thing is, it's not you that is using the `compareTo` function.  You're only honoring the contract that you need to establish for `Collections.sort()` to work properly.  It's actually `Collections.sort()` that makes use of your `compareTo` method, since it only sorts things that are `Comparable`.  The way you would call it would be `Collections.sort(list)`, but I'll add that into the answer.

Comment: Could you please explain a little bit more about why writing `return rating - other.getRating();`? I am totally confused about the compareto function.

Comment: @JayWong: The link in the answer above takes you to the documentation for `Comparable`.  The main principle is that it has to return a negative, zero, or a positive number for less than, equal, or greater than.  Subtracting the two fields we care about is the quickest way to accomplish that, provided the values don't underflow.

Comment: @Makoto: Thank you. Can I interpret like the `Collections.sort()` actually is comparing the return value of my `compareTo` function to achieve sorting?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public class Comparator_Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Players> list = new ArrayList<Players>();      

    Players p1 = new Players(1,92,"Zlatan");
    Players p2 = new Players(2,92,"Hazard");
    Players p3 = new Players(1,82,"Klose");

    list.add(p1);
    list.add(p2);
    list.add(p3);

    PlayerComparator comparator = new PlayerComparator();
    System.out.println(list);
    Collections.sort(list, comparator);
    System.out.println(list);
}

}

class Players {

int position;
     String name;
    int rating;

    public Players(int i, int j, String string)  {

        this.position=i;
        this.rating=j;
        this.name=string;
    }

     public void getRating() {
            System.out.println(this.rating);
            }
     public void getPos() {
            System.out.println(this.position);
            }
     public void getName() {
            System.out.println(this.name);
            }

     public String toString() {
         return rating + "";
     }
}

class PlayerComparator implements Comparator<Players> {

@Override
public int compare(Players o1, Players o2) {
    if(o1.rating > o2.rating) {
        return 1;
    }
    if(o1.rating < o2.rating) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

}
```